# Serializing the result set from the Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-web-api

We created a Web API which queries the Oracle Database and returns the result in JSON format. If the data returned is very large it throws an Out of Exception issue. So it was suggested in the other [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltrP4.jpg) the issue is because loading that entire result set into memory before serializing it out to the `HttpResponseMessage`.

So created the below classes

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(OracleDataTableJsonResponseConverter))]
public sealed class OracleDataTableJsonResponse
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
    public string QueryString { get; private set; }
    public OracleParameter[] Parameters { get; private set; }

    public OracleDataTableJsonResponse(string connStr, string strQuery, OracleParameter[] prms)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connStr;
        this.QueryString = strQuery;
        this.Parameters = prms;
    }
}

class OracleDataTableJsonResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(OracleDataTableJsonResponse);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("OracleDataTableJsonResponse is only for writing JSON.  To read, deserialize into a DataTable");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var response = (OracleDataTableJsonResponse)value;

        using (var dbconn = new OracleConnection(response.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var selectCommand = new OracleCommand(response.QueryString, dbconn))
            {
                if (response.Parameters != null)
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(response.Parameters);

                using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    writer.WriteDataTable(reader, serializer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void WriteDataTable(this JsonWriter writer, IDataReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (writer == null || reader == null || serializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, reader[i]);
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

And the API Controller is

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
{
    var prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    var strQuery = @"SELECT 
                   STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
                   STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
                   Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE, 
                   STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE AS SESSION_START_TIME , 
                   Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.END_DATE) AS SESSION_END_DATE, 
                     FROM 
                     STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR, 
                     WHERE 
                    STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN(";
    var sb = new StringBuilder(strQuery);
    for (int x = 0; x < inconditions.Length; x++)
    {
        sb.Append(":p" + x + ",");
        var p = new OracleParameter(":p" + x, OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        p.Value = inconditions[x];
        prms.Add(p);
    }
    if (inconditions.Length>0)
        sb.Length--;
    strQuery = sb.Append(")").ToString();

    var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=PStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
    {
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }
    return response;
 }
```

The issue now is when I call the API it throws the error an exception in exception is in the `class OracleDataTableJsonResponseConverter` in the statement `using( var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())` saying `invalidOperationException Connection must be open for this operation`

When I tried to debug I see all the connection strings are being passed correctly but it throws error in the server version like below ,
[image]

What could be the issue, I am new to *ASP.NET* and *Oracle* connections and I'm kind of stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I recommend you take a look at micro ORMs (such as Dapper) that solve these simple things as connection state, parameter and result mapping so you don't need to handle that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly open the connection.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var response = (OracleDataTableJsonResponse)value;

    using (var dbconn = new OracleConnection(response.ConnectionString))
    {
        dbconn.Open();
        ...
    }
}
```